# Asp.net button fire in only debug mode but not in others mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following code segment (button firing) is works in debug mode but other than debug mode this button does't work. It works fine in debug mode with break point. When I tried in start without debugging mode the button doesn't work.

.aspx code

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Site Attendance
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjects" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                           
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnPunch" Enabled="true" runat="server" Text="Punch" OnClick="btnPunch_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the .cs code

```
protected void btnPunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
        double la = coord.Latitude;
        double lo = coord.Longitude;

        string userName = null;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            userName = User.Identity.Name;

        List<AppUsers> list = UsersManager.GetByUserName(userName);
        int employeeId = list[0].UserId;

        SitePunch obj = new SitePunch();

        try
        {
            if (la != 0 && lo != 0)
            {
                obj.Employee_ID = Convert.ToInt32(employeeId);
                obj.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(la);
                obj.Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(lo);
                obj.Project_Name = Convert.ToString(ddlProjects.SelectedValue);

                int sitePunchInsert = SitePunchManager.Insert(obj);

                if (sitePunchInsert != 0)
                {
                    ShowMessage("Your Punch is Successful");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ShowMessage("Please Select a Project First");
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the  `UpdateMode` attribute in Updatepanel to "`Conditional`" then added the correct trigger

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPunch" EventName="Click">
            </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If the aboive setting does not work then you can try set `ChildrenAsTriggers` to true and add EventName="Click" in `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger`

Comment: Yes I tried both. Basically I don't understand what is the problem. I tried every possible solution including your but it doesn't work